# Django content type for both static and dynamic content

Tags: django, django-models

we're using Django 1.11 (soon moving to 2.0, so it's OK to answer for that as well).

We are solving the following problem:

1. We have a `Ticket` model with several fields, some of them are `ForeignKey` and some of them are `ChoiceField`.
2. We have a `Condition` model with which we want to target a specific value of some of the `Ticket` fields. If there were just `ForeignKey` fields in `Ticket`, we would use `GenericRelation` (ContentTypes). However there are also "static" values of `ChoiceField`.

One of our colleagues proposed a solution that for every `Condition` we create a hidden instance of `Ticket` that is never used anywhere else and is just there to hold the information about the `ChoiceField` value - and this `Ticket` is then linked to `Condition` through `GenericRelation`. But this sounds like a really bad idea.

I was thinking that many developers had to solve this. Is there any good and easy way how to do this?

Thank you.

EDIT: Concrete models code:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    TYPE_RETURN = 'TYPE_RETURN'
    TYPE_WARRANTY_CLAIM = 'TYPE_WARRANTY_CLAIM'
    TYPES = (
        (TYPE_RETURN, _('Return')),
        (TYPE_WARRANTY_CLAIM, _('Warranty claim'))
    )
    TYPE_DEFAULT = TYPE_RETURN

    state = models.ForeignKey(
        to=TicketState,
        verbose_name=_('State'),
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )

    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=TYPES,
        default=TYPE_DEFAULT
    )

    (...)

class Condition(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=False, editable=True, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    (...)
```

Comment: Could you add your 2 models code (only relevant parts)?

Comment: @OlivierPons Thanks, I have added the models. I'll try to repeat the question in a more clear way: The purpose of `Condition` model is that we want to perform some task (to which this condition is related) only if the `Ticket` in question has some attribute, e.g. a particular `TicketState`. For this we use the generic relation and it works just fine. But now we reached a situation when the attribute is not a model instance (related to `Ticket` through `ForeignKey`) but just a choice in `ChoiceField` - say, we want the condition to be satisfied if the particular ticket has type `TYPE_RETURN`.

Comment: I'm sorry but in your model I dont see any  relationship of any kind between `Ticket` and `Condition`. And you're talking about `ChoiceField` but there's only `type` which is actually *not* a choice field (and it's so weird and risky to use the word `type`... ), so I guess it's the `type` you're talking about.

Comment: I dont understand why you've used `ContentType` with `Condition`. When you use `ContentType` this **implies** that you want your `Condition` to be kind of "generic" and apply condition to a lot of other models. Is this the case, or do you want to use the model `Condition` only with `Ticket`?

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I was not explaining myself clearly. We are not using `ContentType` for `Ticket` model itself, but for different "fields" of `Ticket` model. E.g. `Ticket` can have `TicketState` (as in example) or `TicketTag` or `TicketPriority` or whatever -- all of those are models -- and for this `ContentType` works just fine. However, `Ticket` can have also other "static" (`ChoiceField`) fields such as `type` or `language` or `country` etc. [Thanks for the `type` keyword warning, I agree with you.]